# How were Ceasar's troops supplied with food during the Siege of Alexandria?

Tags: ancient-rome, war, roman-empire, egypt, julius-caesar

During the [Siege of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Alexandria_(47_BC)), Julius Ceasar and a few thousand troops were stuck in the royal quarter of Alexandria for several months, with a local army surrounding them.

Did the royal quarter have a massive stockpile of grain (enough to feed thousands of soldiers for several months), or did they somehow get supplies past the besieging army (perhaps through the port?)

**Edit:** Thanks, @Evargalo for the quote on the reinforcements from his Thirty-seventh legion. How did that shipment make it through the siege? Was there only one shipment, or several? If one, was that enough to last for all the months?

Comment: FWIW, the wiki page says: "Caesar's water supplies were contaminated, forcing him to dig wells. Reinforcements from his Thirty-seventh legion, a former Pompeian formation, also then arrived by sea bringing supplies and artillery.", citing "Goldsworthy, Adrian (2006). Caesar: Life of a Colossus. Yale University Press. ISBN 978-0-300-13919-8." as a source.

Comment: Note that the 37th legion delivery was made by sea, which means that the Roman fleet kept communications opened. Which is not a surprise since Caesar made a raid to the Alexandrian fleet and burnt it down (again, the wikipedia article in the link), and destroyed in a fight the survivors. So overall the answer is: sea power helped Caesar to handle the siege